# Lock to one tab during Login Android

Tags: java, android, tabs, facebook-login

I'm using the default Action Bar/Swipe Tabs view for my android app. I'm using 3 tabs, with the middle tab being the start tab as well as the login tab. Is it possible to lock the tab (so users can't swipe to the others) well not logged in/until they login? The middle tab with the login is a fragment that contains a login button widget as well as all the UI cycle stuff.

My login and logout is working, I would just like it to prevent swiping until logged in.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Override Listeners for swiping/change tab. 
For example, keep boolean flag and check it in listener. If ok - swipe